# How to get Build output, error list, when running Project.Build() in a custom build task?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

**Environment:**

C# projects, Visual studio 2008, C#, .Net 3.5, MSBuild

**Objective:**

Run my own custom build task for my C# projects, and based on the platform (Soln configuration platform), I do some manipulations to the Project object itself before build. Like setting BuildAction to EmbeddedResource etc.

Once that's done I call `Project.Build()`. I don't want to use the Project object on the GlobalEngine, because it is going to mark the file dirty (and checkout from TFS), once you modify the Project object in anyway.

**Problem:**

Because I am using my own instance of the Engine, and Project, I am not able to direct the build output, errors to VS. I only get a bool out of `Project.Build()`.
I don't find any events I could hook up to that can allow access to `BuildErrorEventArgs` and things like that. I know I can use `Log.LogErrorEvent()` to log messages to VS error list. But I need to get the build output itself first to do that.

**Code:**

```
// Execute method in my custom build task class, derives from a BaseTask class
public override bool Execute()
{
Engine engine = new Engine();
Project project = new Project(engine);
project.Load(ProjectName);
Log.LogMessage(Microsoft.Build.Framework.MessageImportance.High, "Got the Project");
// Set the project's DefaultTargets to "Build" to be able to build with CSharp targets
project.DefaultTargets = "Build";
IsBuilt = project.Build(); // Isbuilt bool is a property in my BaseTask class
// Here's where I want to get Build output and direct it to VS output window and errorlist window

engine.Shutdown();
return base.Execute();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, simply implement a custom logger and use Log.LogMessage or LogError in the event handlers

```
public class MyCustomBuildLogger : ILogger
{
    private IEventSource source;

 public void Initialize(IEventSource eventSource)
        {
            this.source = eventSource;
            //Events.ProjectStarted += new ProjectStartedEventHandler(Events_ProjectStarted);
            //Events.ProjectFinished += new ProjectFinishedEventHandler(Events_ProjectFinished);
            Events.WarningRaised += new BuildWarningEventHandler(Events_WarningRaised);
            Events.ErrorRaised += new BuildErrorEventHandler(Events_ErrorRaised);
            Events.BuildFinished += new BuildFinishedEventHandler(Events_BuildFinished);
            //Events.BuildStarted += new BuildStartedEventHandler(Events_BuildStarted);
            Events.MessageRaised += new BuildMessageEventHandler(Events_MessageRaised);
            //Events.CustomEventRaised += new CustomBuildEventHandler(Events_CustomEventRaised);

            Events.MessageRaised += new BuildMessageEventHandler(Events_MessageRaised);
        }

 void Events_ErrorRaised(object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // This logs the error to VS Error List tool window
            Log.LogError(String.Empty, 


             String.Empty,
                    String.Empty, 
                    e.File, 
                    e.LineNumber, 
                    e.ColumnNumber,
                    e.LineNumber, 
                    e.ColumnNumber, 
                    e.Message);
           }
}
```

and in the MyCustomBuildTask class, where you setup and load the engine and project,

```
_logger = new MyCustomBuildLogger();
_logger.Log = Log;
_engine.RegisterLogger(_logger);
```